# XSLT is converting my hex attributes to something else, how do I stop it?

Tags: xslt, hex

I'm trying to transform one xml file to output another xml file, and I need the attribute "account" to be output identically to how it appears below. I have a bunch of these values in the file, most are not working.

For values of account like 0x0406 it is output as 0.0.06. But for values like 0x002d it leaves them alone and they come through the way I want.

Any ideas?

Initial XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<foo account="0x0406" other-stuff="blah" something-name="blah again"/>
...
```

This is my xslt template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:user="http://some-internal-thing/user">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
...
<xsl:attribute name="account"><xsl:value-of select="@account"/></xsl:attribute>
...
```

Comment: That sounds very odd. XSLT should always handle attribute values as plain strings unless told to do something else. I don't think the error is in the part you've pasted.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, can you give us a complete (small) example and step-by-step instructions to reproduce that result?

Comment: Please also mention which XSLT implementation you're using.

Comment: I tried testing this with both xsltproc and saxon, and this didn't happen.  Can you post a full sample XML/XSLT pair with the problem rather than these abbreviated ones that I had to modify to use?

Comment: Thank you all for the confirmation that this wasn't XSLT related - turns out earlier in the process I had sed replacing the literal string 0.0.0 in the xml file, and it wasn't qouted, so it was replacing anything that matched that regex and messing with my attributes without my realizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The described problem cannot be reproduced**.

I have run the following transformation with **10 different xslt processors** (Msxml3, Msxml4, Msxml6, .NET XslTransform, .NET XslCompiledTransform, AltovaXml(for XSLT 1.01.0), Saxon6.5.4, Saxon 9.1.07, Saxon 9.1.07.NET and XML-SPY-XSLT2.0) and they **all produce the same correct result**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:user="http://some-internal-thing/user">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="account"><xsl:value-of select="@account"/></xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is performed on the following XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo account="0x0406" other-stuff="blah" something-name="blah again"/>
```

**the expected, correct result is produced**:

```
<foo account="0x0406" />
```

In case your XSLT processor is not one of these and you *really* get a wrong result, this is a bug and should be reported to the vendors.

Comment: Wow, 10 different XSLT processors - I wish I had that kind of time on my hands. Thanks for the confirmation, it made me look at everything else besides XSLT, and It turns out I had sed touching the XML file earlier in my process and replacing the literal string 0.0.0, which of course wasn't quoted, and so it was replacing that regex. I hate inheriting code.

Comment: @wonderfulthunk: I am glad that this helped. Believe me or not, but this took me just 2-3 minutes. I am using an XSLT IDE that allows to perform any transformation with any XSLT processor (already installed) in just one or two clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the encoding ? For example "ASCII" instead of "UTF-8".

Comment: People still use ASCII? In this day and age?

Comment: Or just remove the encoding from the source XML's declaration altogether and let the XSLT engine detect.  Maybe your source file is NOT UTF-8.

Comment: I couldn't try ASCII, I have unicode characters in my xml file and I get errors when trying ASCII.